# Alternative to navigator.storage.estimate() on Safari

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I want to let my users know how much space my PWA is taking on their machines, For Firefox and Chrome I can use the `navigator.storage.estimate()` function but this is not supported on Safari.

Is there any alternative? My research seem to indicate there isn't which I have hard to believe.

Note: my tests show that on Safari 14.1.2 the deprecated APIs `window.webkitStorageInfo` and `navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage` are not supported either